# grep: --exclude-dir don't work

Tags: grep

I want to tell `grep`, on Debian, not to search through files in `/proc` or `/sys`. But if I use:

```
 --exclude-dir=/proc
```

or

```
--exclude-dir={/proc,/sys}
```

or

```
--exclude-dir=/proc --exclude-dir=/sys
```

Then `grep` still read `/sys` and crashes because of that. So how can I tell `grep` to skip the `/proc` and `/sys` directories?

Comment: First, what exactly are you trying to do? Are you searching for a pattern recursively?

Comment: I already answered my question. Moderator has just deleted it

Comment: Sorry about that. Since there was no actual question here, I thought you were wondering why these fail, not how to do it. And someone else must have thought so as well since they had edited your answer into your question.

Comment: It isn't a possible duplicate

Comment: @don_crissti it's not a duplicate of that. Is there a q&a about how grep's `--exclude-dir` is matching directory names (eg. `sys`), not paths (eg. `/sys`)?

Comment: @mosvy - yeah, not a dupe... retracting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

However, this works well!

```
 --exclude-dir={proc,sys}
```

Comment: Sorry! I misunderstood completely and thought your question was "why does `--exclude-dir=/proc` and `--exclude-dir=/proc --exclude-dir=/sys` not work. So an answer would explain why those fail, not give a command that works. If you are instead asking "how can I do this", then this is indeed an answer and I was wrong to delete it. If this is the case, could you please also edit your question so what you are asking is clearer?

Comment: Someone has already done it, but thanks for your kindness !

Comment: Hmmm.... I would be interested in knowing what the difference between `proc` and `/proc` would be and why using `/proc` does not exclude the `/proc` directory.  It seems to me that using `proc` would make `grep` also exclude directories with this name in other parts of the directory structure.

Comment: I read in first time in a other place that it take /proc but ./proc too.
And i read here that because i have precised "/" in the location of search, grep does need to read proc and not /proc, because it's relative to where he begin to search

Comment: @Kusalananda maybe because `--exclude-dir`'s pattern should match the *name*, not the *path* of the directory?

Comment: @mosvy I know. I discuss this in my answer as it's missing from this one.

Comment: @Kusalananda sorry, I have missed your answer.

Answer (score 9):

The documentatiton for `--exclude-dir` in the GNU `grep` manual says

> `--exclude-dir=GLOB`
>
> Skip any command-line directory with a name suffix that matches
>             the pattern `GLOB`.  When searching recursively, skip any
>             subdirectory whose base name matches `GLOB`.  Ignore any redundant
>             trailing slashes in `GLOB`.

As you can see, the given pattern (`GLOB`) will be applied only to the actual filename of the directory, and since a directory name can't contain `/` in its name, a pattern like `/proc` will never match.

Therefore, you would have to use `--exclude-dir=proc` and `--exclude-dir=sys` (or `--exclude-dir={proc,sys}` if you are short on time), and at the same time be aware that this would skip not only `/proc` and `/sys` but also any *other* directory with either of those names.

Another way of recursively searching a complete directory tree from the root down while avoiding these two directories is by using `grep` from `find`:

```
find / \( -type d \( -path /proc -o -path /sys \) -prune \) -o \
    -type f -exec grep 'PATTERN' {} +
```

This would detect the two *specific* directories `/proc` and `/sys` and stop `find` from descending into them.  It would also feed any found regular file to `grep` in as large batches as possible at a time.

Comment: why do you use `-prune`?

Comment: @Shuzheng To stop `find` from entering those directories.

Comment: ♦ - Will you elaborate? What directories specifically?

Comment: @Shuzheng `/proc` and `/sys`.  These are the directories that the user in the question wants to avoid.

Comment: Couldn't this be written using negation instead? `! \( -path /proc -o -path /sys \)`?

Comment: @Shuzheng That would stop `grep` from being executed with files from those directories, yes, but it would not have stopped `find` from trying to access everything inside `/sys` and `/proc`.  The `-prune` predicate "prunes" (removes) a directory tree from the search tree.

Comment: Ahh, I see! So, exactly does `-prune` know which directories to apply to? Is it always the directories on the left side of the invisible `-a` (AND)?

Comment: @Shuzheng You typically use `-prune` to stop `find` from even considering the files and directories beneath a path. In this case, we don't want to pass e.g. `/proc/uptime` or `/proc/version` or any of the other thousands of pathnames under `/proc`.  It is more efficient to ignore `/proc` than to test each and every name under `/proc` against some pattern.

Comment: @Shuzheng `-prune` is an "action". It acts on the current pathname, just like `-print` does.

Comment: +1 for this quote "the given pattern (GLOB) will be applied only to the actual filename of the directory, and since a directory name can't contain / in its name, a pattern like /proc will never match." ... That answers my question that drew me here: why isn't it excluding a sub-path like 'configs/users'.

Answer (score -1):

You must know that grep will take the selected directory as the base for the file names on the search, because that on the search list they will be showed as dev/, sys/ etc. so instead of using:

```
grep 'yourstring' -R --exclude-dir={/dev,/sys,/proc} /
```

You must use:

```
grep 'yourstring '-R --exclude-dir={dev/,sys/,proc/} /
```

Comment: That's what i said but a moderator has deleted my answer. So we can't answer ourselves here.
"But --exclude-dir={proc,sys} works well !"