# How does "diff --exclude" work?

Tags: diff

I'm trying to use `diff` to compare two directory trees while ignoring certain sub-directories, but I cannot get it to work. This is what my file structure looks like:

```
temp/
|-- d1/
|   |-- f1.txt
|   `-- ignoreme/
|       `-- f2.txt
`-- d2/
    |-- f1.txt
    `-- ignoreme/
        `-- f2.txt
```

I'm trying to get it to ignore anything under `d1/ignoreme` and `d2/ignoreme`, but it won't do it.

```
diff -qr --exclude=/home/ubuntu/temp/d1/ignoreme/ d1 d2
Files d1/ignoreme/f2.txt and d2/ignoreme/f2.txt differ
```

I also tried

```
diff -qr --exclude=/home/ubuntu/temp/d1/ignoreme/* d1 d2
```

and

```
diff -qr --exclude=/home/ubuntu/temp/d1/ignoreme/* --exclude=/home/ubuntu/temp/d2/ignoreme/* d1 d2
```

... but I always get the same result.

How do I get this to work?

Comment: related https://stackoverflow.com/a/78020334/1824361

Answer (score 65, accepted):

The `-x` or `--exclude` options for GNU `diff` take a filename globbing pattern that the name of each file and directory will be matched against.  If the pattern matches a particular name, that name is excluded from comparison.

The pattern is applied to the basename of files and directories, not to pathnames, which means that to exclude your `ignoreme` directory, you would use

```
diff -qr --exclude=ignoreme ...
```

This would also exclude any other name that happens to be `ignoreme`.

This is similar to [the way that `--exclude` and `--exclude-dir` works in GNU `grep`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/493723/grep-exclude-dir-dont-work) when running `grep` recursively, although the GNU `grep` manual explains this better.

[The `info` documentation for GNU `diff`](https://www.gnu.org/software/diffutils/manual/html_node/diff-Options.html#diff-Options) spells it out:

> `-x PATTERN`
>   `--exclude=PATTERN`
>        When comparing directories, ignore files and subdirectories whose
>        basenames match `PATTERN`.

Comment: thanks for pointing "The pattern is applied to the basename of files and directories, not to pathnames". its very helpful.